# Capture video from firewire cameras

Tags: cocoa, video, opencv, camera

I am working on a project where I need to capture video from two firewire cameras and do some processing on them.  The one caveat is that I need to control the camera features (gain, gamma, white balance, etc).

After searching around I found two projects that seem to work.  One is a cocoa project that interfaces with opencv but as far as I know, I can access the camera features through that code.  The other is an openframeworks project that does allow me to access the features of the camera but doesn't currently interface with opencv.

I'm thinking about trying to combine the two projects and use the openframeworks one to set the camera features and the cocoa one to capture the images and do the processing.  Is that a feasible idea or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

openFrameworks interfaces with openCv. There's an addon called ofxOpenCv and there are a couple of examples using it in openFrameworks/apps/addonsExamples